In the expression どちらかというと, would you say the か-particle is interrogative or adverbial?
(as specified on imabi: https://imabi.org/the-particle-ka-%e3%81%8b-iii-indirect-question/ under  the subheading "interrogative + か" )
I.e. do you see the どちらか part as "whichever", or "which+か" (or something else)?
Am I correct in interpreting it as: どちら＋か＋というと, translating into something like "If one were to say + which ~".
Context sentence:
つまり、「へ」はどちらかというとかなり正式な場面・・・によく使って
(from:) https://youtu.be/F8l0th2jLks?t=110

と is a quotative particle, so the part before it (どちらか) can be interpretated as an independent sentence. Unlike an adverb, どちらか by itself does not directly modify something.

どちらか?
Which?
どちらかというと
If one says "Which"?
→ If anything / If you ask / If I need to choose one

